# Apache SVN module do not list permissioned subfolders in web view

Tags: apache, svn, ldap, repository, svn-server

I've builded up a SVN server in a Ubuntu 16 LTS instance connected with a AD via LDAP. My problem is: I can't setup the Apache or the SVN module to list the subfolders of a repository when a user does not have R permission on the root level of the repository.

**Example:**

```
[RepositoryABC]
user1=rw
user2=r

[RepositoryABC:/folder]
user3=rw
```

When the user1 and user2 access the SVN via the web view provided by the SVN Apache module both can see the RepositoryABC. But if the user3 try the same he/she will get a empty page although he/she has permission in the subfolder.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you might try to add `user3` to root directory with `r`, and then hide undesired folders from him, like:

```
[RepositoryABC]
user1=rw
user2=r
user3=r

[RepositoryABC:/OTHER_FOLDER_1_YOU_WANT_TO_HIDE_FROM_USER3]
user3=(syntax that hides)
[RepositoryABC:/OTHER_FOLDER_2_YOU_WANT_TO_HIDE_FROM_USER3]
user3=(syntax that hides)

[RepositoryABC:/folder]
user3=rw
```

just an idea, untested.

Comment: `syntax that hides` would be?

Comment: @MarceloFilho it's you who should write that, I exactly dont know the specifics of AD/LDAP and there should exist a value (instead of `r/rw`) which will forbid any access to those folders.